# Android AppCompatTextView Throwing OutOfMemoryError

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a `<TextView/>` that I replaced with a `<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView />` so that the text would dynamically resize according to how much text was being displayed.

As soon as I replaced the `<Textview />` with `<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView />` the app suffered a memory leak.

The view is part of and `ViewPager` and the app can handle about 70 pages before it runs out of memory and throws `OutOfMemoryError`.

So this works fine with hundreds of pages:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/my_text_view_1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/black"
    android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
    android:text="Welcome to My App!"
    android:textSize="48dp"
    android:gravity="center" />
```

And this throws the error after about 70 pages are loaded (I did remove the extra properties just to test):

```
<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
    android:id="@+id/my_text_view_1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/black_overlay"
    android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="Welcome to My App!"
    app:autoSizeMaxTextSize="128dp"
    app:autoSizeMinTextSize="28dp"
    app:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="160dp"/>
```

Three questions:

1. I have found older mentions of a bug with AppCompatTextView.... is that what I am seeing here?
2. Is there anything else that needs to be done to drop in the AppCompatTextView in place of TextView?
3. Is there an alternative way to dynamically resize text based on # of characters (goal being to occupy the entire view)?

Comment: If you are using a `Theme.AppCompat` theme for your activity, then `<TextView>` tags are _already_ inflated as `AppCompatTextView`s

Comment: In case it was not obvious, the implication of the above is that _something else_ is responsible for this change in behavior, not TextView vs AppCompatTextView.

Comment: Additionally, `ViewPager` should behave like other adapter-backed widgets, and only actually keep a small number of pages alive in memory. There shouldn't be any difference between 70 and 700 pages (assuming you aren't changing the offscreen page limit) unless you've got a memory leak somewhere.

Comment: @BenP. When no other code is changed except `<TextView` being replaced with `<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView` I can't see how it's something else. There is no leak when using `<TextView`.

Comment: Are you using a `Theme.AppCompat` theme? If you stop your app with a debugger breakpoint, can you see what class `<TextView>` tags are inflated as?

Comment: @BenP. I am using a custom theme with `Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar` as parent. The only class I see in debugger is `java.lang.String` which is probably not what you're asking for.